# Creating a DLL from a Simulink model

Tags: c++, matlab, dll, simulink

I'm trying to create a simple DLL for a Simulink model which basically multiplies an input by a constant value. I have generated the code for a shared library using the embedded coder and a makefile is present as well.

Is it possible to create a DLL from this?

I'm new to DLLs and back-end development and therefore any leads would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: A DLL is just the usual Windows terminology for a shared library. What platform are you aiming for?

Comment: A DLL is a format for shared libraries on Windows. Depending on what platform you compile your shared library, it will either be a .dll file (Windows), a .dylib file (macOS) or a .so file (Linux).

Answer (score 0):

You can use ert_shrlib.tlc if you have the Embedded Coder product to generate generic DLLs from your Simulink model. The relevant documentation is here: [Package Generated Code as Shared Libraries](https://es.mathworks.com/help/ecoder/ug/creating-and-using-host-based-shared-libraries.html)